# Is this answer of mine suitable to be left here?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

[EF 4.1 exception "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423278/ef-4-1-the-provider-did-not-return-a-providermanifesttoken-string/7313568#7313568)

I got a similar error as the questioner, but in a later non CTP version of an MS product. When searching SO for this issue, it was reading the answers in this question that lead me deduce the answer to my particular issue. Hence me leaving that answer.

Now I'm not so sure as whether this is the right place.

Comment: I edited your answer; your reticence at the start was confusing and made it appear you weren't actually answering the question.  I hope my edit helped make it clear 1) what was actually happening and 2) that the cause isn't specific to the OP's (or even your) example.

Comment: @Won't - excellent!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's a fine answer. It may not solve the OP's issue, but if it helped you, and your symptoms matched those of the OP, then it might help someone else.

Comment: I'll definitely agree here - while posting simply "I have this problem also" wouldn't have been an answer, you also did give some idea of what may help the problem (what helped you, anyway) - that's plenty enough to escape the realm of being a poor answer, in my eyes.